# jquery - insert variable into DOM attribute declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to javascript and jquery, and was having an issue with a small project to train with.

I have a for loop in my javascript code that is supposed to `append` a new `<div>` to one already present in the DOM, and to keep it unique, its id is appended with the id of the object it is supposed to represent. However, I'm not entirely sure how to insert this variable into the `<div>` declaration. Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Here's the block of code:

```
var progressdiv_id = 'progressdiv' + data[ i ][ 'active_report_thread' ][ 'thread_id' ];
var progressbar_id = 'progressbar' + data[ i ][ 'active_report_thread' ][ 'thread_id' ];
var progressbar_style = 'width: ' + data[ i ][ 'active_report_thread' ][ 'progress' ] + '%';
$( '#progressbars' ).append( '<div class="row"><div id=progressdiv_id class="progress progress-striped active span6"><div id=progressbar_id class="bar" style=progressbar_style></div></div></div>' );
```

I've attempted to insert the variable names into the `<div>` declaration, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to **build** the string (representing DOM element) that you want to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can handle this. But, to cut to the chase:

```
var progressdiv_id = 'progressdiv' + data[ i ][ 'active_report_thread' ][ 'thread_id' ];
var progressbar_id = 'progressbar' + data[ i ][ 'active_report_thread' ][ 'thread_id' ];
var progressbar_style = 'width: ' + data[ i ][ 'active_report_thread' ][ 'progress' ] + '%';
$( '#progressbars' ).append( '<div class="row"><div id="'+progressdiv_id+'" class="progress progress-striped active span6"><div id="'+progressbar_id+'" class="bar" style="'+progressbar_style+'"></div></div></div>' );
```

Javascript has no "native" way to handle string interpolation; which is what you'd need to handle the type of syntax you were providing. Instead, you have to concatenate variables onto strings. I would probably create and cache a few jQuery objects and manipulate only the parts I needed in each iteration of your loop and append them all at the end. Or, use a template engine like [riot.js](https://moot.it/riotjs/) to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yours and user3003977's suggestions were both good, but ultimately I went with something similar to what you suggested before even coming back to the question, so I'll select it.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can pass attributes like this to create your div or HTML elements;

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
id: 'progressdiv_id',
href: 'http://here if it is an anchor',
title: 'some title',
text: 'some text'
}).appendTo('#TargetDiv');
```

You can use also `.html()` instead of `.append()` to insert into the target Element

You combine string (concatenation) using the `+` operator, same applies for variables that are considered as containers and hold any type of data(string or numbers ) so when combining a variable with a string is the same as joining two strings

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like how neat it is, but ultimately I went with something similar to what mneil suggested before coming back to check this question. Thanks again for your help!